# How do I INSERT multiple rows (~70k) faster in MySQL using PHP and PDO if the values are inside an array made from another table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to insert multiple rows into a truncated table and while the process works it takes a long time to finish. With around ~800 rows it's already taking me 60+ seconds to finish, which is already problematic considering I have to do the same process for a table with ~70k rows (I did the math and it would have took around 1 hour and 45 mins to finish). Here is the code:

```
set_time_limit(5000); //bypass 30s limit

$serverName = "<servername>";
$connectionInfo_mssql = array("Database"=>"<dbname>", "CharacterSet"=>"UTF-8");

try
  {
    $conn_mssql = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$serverName;Database=<dbname>");
    $conn_mssql->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $conn_mysql = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=<dbname>", "<user>", "<pass>");
    $conn_mysql->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


    //SELECT FROM SQL SERVER DB
    $mssql_array = array();
    $mssql_query = $conn_mssql->prepare("SELECT * FROM Awards");
    $mssql_query->execute();

    while($row = $mssql_query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH))
    {

      $mssql_array[] = array('id' => $row['id'], 
                             'IDNO' => $row["IDNO"], 
                             'title' => $row['title'], 
                             'place' => $row['place'],
                             'awarded' => $row['awarded'],
                             'datee' => $row['datee']);

    }
    //empties out the MySQL Table
    $mysql_query = $conn_mysql->prepare("TRUNCATE TABLE Awards");
    $mysql_query->execute();

    if($mysql_query)
    {
      echo "Truncate Success"."<br>";
    }
    else
    {
      echo "Truncate Error";
    }
    //inserts values from SQL Server DB to the empty MySQL Table
    $sql = $conn_mysql->prepare("INSERT INTO Awards VALUES (:id, :IDNO, :title, :place, :awarded, :datee)");
    foreach($mssql_array as $key => $value)
    {
      $params_insert = array(':id' => $value['id'], 
                             ':IDNO' => $value['IDNO'], 
                             ':title' => $value['title'], 
                             ':place' => $value['place'],
                             ':awarded' => $value['awarded'],
                             ':datee' => $value['datee']);

      $sql->execute($params_insert);
    }

    echo 'Table Awards from MS SQL DB and table Awards from MySQL DB are now synced!'."<br>";
    echo "<a href='table_updater.php'>Go back to updater</a>";

  }
catch(PDOException $e)
  {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
  }

?>
```

I searched for answers from past questions about this particular problem but almost all of them deals with variables with fixed values. I have no idea how to apply that to my code considering I'm using an array to store all the values from the main table. What should I change/add to my code to make it faster?

Comment: If you're doing 800 rows in 60 seconds that's only 13 inserts per second and that seems extraordinarily slow, especially for something with a prepared statement involved. Is the database really busy? Is there a lot of indexes on that table? You could try benchmarking versus a direct CSV insert, that's often the fastest, to see where the performance bottleneck is. This *should* be fast, like at least 100 per second if not more, especially on a server with ~4GB of memory and a mid-range SSD for storage.

Comment: I would not use php to transfer so much data between databases. The two servers can obviiysly see each other, so I would add the mysql servers as a linked server to the ms sql server (you need to install myodbc on the ms sql server). Then directly transfer the data. Or install an ETL tool, such as SSIS and use that to transfer the data. Or just dump the ms sql data as a csv file and use load data infile to load it into mysql.

Comment: @tadman I have a separate code that compares both tables and inserts only the differences. This one works almost completely instant, but the problem is for some reason it only works for one table. I know the insertion process is different for both but the difference is a lot

Comment: The real question here is do the inserts get incrementally slower with each row inserted, which indicates some kind of index performance problem, or is it consistently slow regardless of how big the table is? A badly tuned MySQL server may have some really ridiculous defaults, like giving InnoDB only 32MB (megabytes!) of memory when your system may have vastly more memory to work with.

Comment: Although this is edging into [DBA territory](https://dba.stackexchange.com/), you may want to observe server performance with a tool like [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) to see what kind of performance you're actually getting. You'll also want to compare doing this from a static file (e.g. CSV dump or JSON file, whatever's easy to work with) into PHP and eliminate the SQL Server part of the equation. Process of reduction! Like does this insert quickly onto some other MySQL server? Or a newer version of MySQL?

Comment: It's consistently slow, I tested the same code on a table with ~160 rows and it took around 8-10 seconds to finish. I did the math and it inserts at the same rate as your estimated inserts per second. What should I check for next and is it possible to make this work faster inside PHP?

Comment: take a look at batch insert  ..  (insert multiple rows with each single query)  instead of a single insert you could prerare bacth of 10 or 50 or more and improve performance